Google Sheet insertion data with PHP
I'm trying to insert data into a google sheet, but I always get this error.
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: implode(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\gsheet\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Service\Resource.php:291 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsheet\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Service\Resource.php(291): implode(Array, '&') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsheet\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Service\Resource.php(190): Google_Service_Resource->createRequestUri('v4/spreadsheets...', Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsheet\vendor\google\apiclient-services\src\Sheets\Resource\SpreadsheetsValues.php(84): Google_Service_Resource->call('append', Array, 'Google\\Service\\...') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsheet\index.php(26): Google\Service\Sheets\Resource\SpreadsheetsValues->append('1yZUoDf5M7AbITR...', 'Sheet1', Object(Google\Service\Sheets\ValueRange), Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsheet\index.php(48): send_to_google_sheets(Array) #5 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\gsheet\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Service\Resource.php on line 291

this is my code
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; 

function send_to_google_sheets($data)
{
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig('service-account.json');
    $client->addScope(\Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');

    $service = new \Google_Service_Sheets($client);

    $spreadsheetId = 'google_spreadsheet_id';
    $range = 'Sheet1';

    try {
        $values = ['Joseph','Tester','test.o@demo.com'];
        //execute the request
        $body = new \Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
            'values' => $values
        ]);
        $params = [
            'valueInputOption' => 'RAW'
        ];
        $result = $service->spreadsheets_values->append($spreadsheetId, $range, $body, $params);
        printf("%d cells appended.", $result->getUpdates()->getUpdatedCells());
        return $result;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Message: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

 
send_to_google_sheets($form_data);

I just need to insert the flat data at the end of the file in the Google Sheet, it's something simple but it's become too complicated for me. I must add that I try to do the insertion when a form is being processed, I want everything on the server side.

In your showing script, $values is a 1-dimensional array. At "Method: spreadsheets.values.append", the value is required to be a 2-dimensional array. I guess that the reason for your current issue might be due to this. So, how about modifying your script as follows?
From:
$values = ['Joseph','Tester','test.o@demo.com'];

To:
$values = [['Joseph','Tester','test.o@demo.com']];


In this modification, $values is appended as a row.

Reference:

Method: spreadsheets.values.append


Same error after editing the code.
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: implode(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\gsheet\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Service\Resource.php:291 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsheet\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Service\Resource.php(291): implode(Array, '&') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsheet\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Service\Resource.php(190): Google_Service_Resource->createRequestUri('v4/spreadsheets...', Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\gsheet\vendor\google\a

@Joseph Olivas Thank you for replying. About Same error after editing the code., I remembered the change of specification of PHP. About implode(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?, if you are using php v8, the specification of implode has been changed. So, please confirm the line 291 of the file C:\xampp\htdocs\gsheet\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Service\Resource.php. Then, please modify $requestUrl .= '?' . implode($queryVars, '&'); to $requestUrl .= '?' . implode('&', $queryVars); and test it again.

@Joseph Olivas When you modify it and reflect my modification to your script, I confirmed that the issue was resolved. So, please modify it and test it again.
